# Download of remote sensing STAC using new rsi package: Warning: Failed to download No such file or directory (GDAL error 4)

Tags: r, rsi

Using the new [rsi package](https://permian-global-research.github.io/rsi/articles/rsi.html) examples I am unable to access remote sensing data.

```
our_aoi <- sf::st_bbox(
  c(xmin = 200000, ymin = 900000, xmax = 200100, ymax = 900100), 
  crs = 26986
)
our_aoi <- sf::st_as_sf(sf::st_as_sfc(our_aoi))
sf::st_area(our_aoi)
#> 10000 [m^2]
plot(sf::st_geometry(our_aoi))

EcoZone <- rsi::get_landsat_imagery(
  # Spatial AOI:
  aoi = our_aoi,
  # Temporal AOI:
  start_date = "2023-08-15",
  end_date = "2023-08-30",
  output_filename = tempfile(fileext = ".tif"))


EcoZone_lcpri
#> [1] "/tmp/RtmpOHg0Pw/file1f8337225bf0.tif"
```

#Example from [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2024/01/an-overview-of-the-rsi-r-package-for-retrieving-satellite-imagery-and-calculating-spectral-indices/):

```
san_antonio = sf::st_point(c(-98.491142, 29.424349))
san_antonio = sf::st_sfc(san_antonio, crs = "EPSG:4326")
san_antonio = sf::st_buffer(sf::st_transform(san_antonio, "EPSG:3081"), 5000)

sa_landsat = rsi::get_landsat_imagery(
    san_antonio,
    start_date = "2023-09-01",
    end_date = "2023-10-31",
    output_filename = tempfile(fileext = ".tif")
)
sa_landsat
```

With either of those examples I get:

```
Warning: Failed to download LC09_L2SP_012031_20230826_02_T1 from 2023-08-26T15:27:00.693890Z [...]: No such file or directory (GDAL error 4)Error: [rast] file does not exist: C:\Users\MEHERE\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMHBvri\file6db853474688.tif
```

I restarted "R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)" using latest RStudio.
These are the packages I am using for my session:

```
list.of.packages <- c("stringr","here","terra","class","reshape","ggplot2","sf","XML","exiftoolr","curl","RCurl","httr","ncdf4","future","rsi","rstac")
```

Comment: Might have timed out? Try including `options(timeout = 600)` before you run the commands

Comment: I tried this (did not work) and do not believe this to be the issue. I am working on high-speed fiber optic with a very fast machine. Also I used the rsi example for a 9-pixel toy, so it is a very small download. I should mention that my colleague can get this to work on his computer. I re-installed R and rebooted. I also tried updating to the development version without success.

Comment: The error indicates that the file exists but is not valid tif (e.g. corrupt; per https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240513/gdal-and-error-4). I'm not sure why this would be the case. Loading your list of packages (as ordered in the `list.of.packages` vector) and using your example code worked on my system too. If possible, please include the version of curl you have installed (i.e. when I type `library(curl)` it prints "Using libcurl 8.4.0 with LibreSSL/3.3.6") and edit your question to include the output of the command `sessionInfo()` @Mark Thompson; hopefully something will stand out.

Comment: No warning(s), but no values, so blank plot, `curl_version() [1] "7.81.0"` for your above our_aoi and san_antonio. Final ?rsi::get_landsat_imagery example, using your `our_aoi` and example dates, returns `beat_does_corner.tif`, with values for A:T1. And plots. There's lots of reading to do to appreciate what's on offer, but you use and asset name as variable LHS without asset name in call, so perhaps that's something to look into.

Comment: I checked and loaded the latest curl_version() [1] $version [1] "8.3.0", also 1.98-1.14 in package view window. This does not fix the problem. I also get this error if I run the example in ?rsi::get_landsat_imagery.

Comment: This is embarrassing. The problem was that my RStudio was specifically loading an older version of R!!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is a bit embarrassing, but perhaps a lesson. My RStudio was calling to an older version of R. I had recently switched to my laptop while my desktop was out for repair. I updated everything, but discovered that RStudio was explicitly set to load an older R version in an older folder despite my recent R update to a new folder.

I discovered this in putting a report together where I ran citation() and noticed that the R version was old.

Comment: That's frustrating but I'm glad you solved your issue @Mark :)